# How to get rid of frame around my social icons?

Tags: html, css

I can't get rid of the frame around my social icons (see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7g8r/2/ ). I tried `Img border: 0` and "none" but without success. What is wrong? Thanks.

CSS

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
.social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 13px;
    text-align: right;
}


.social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

}
.social li {
    margin: 2px;
}

.fbbl, .fbbw, .linkedinbl, .linkedinbw, .vimeobl, .vimeobw{
    background: url(images/sprites.png) no-repeat;

}



.fbbw{
    background-position: -51px -1px ;
    width: 34px;
    height: 35px;
}

.fbbw:hover{
    background-position: -1px 0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}



.linkedinbw{
    background-position: -51px -103px ;
    width: 34px;
    height: 35px;
}
.linkedinbw:hover{
    background-position: 0 -50px ;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}


.vimeobw{
    background-position: -49px -52px ;
    width: 34px;
    height: 35px;
}
.vimeobw:hover{
    background-position: 0 -103px ;
    width: 33px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="social">
          <ul>
            <li><img class="fbbw"></li>
            <li><img class="linkedinbw"></li>
            <li><img class="vimeobw"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: there isn't a border in any browsers except webkit ones, but there is no border set. The image url is broken, so the images do not show. Are you sure it is not just the broken image icon in webkit? Have you tried with valid images?

Comment: The weird thing is that looking at the computed style doesn't help at all… I can't find where does this border come from… Very interesting! Also I'd like to note that your code doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Hi David - see results with a valid image: http://jsfiddle.net/r7g8r/2/ Same issue Tks

Comment: @DavidStorey I have tried. Anyway, you should admit, that it would be a _weird_ choise of a default broken image icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *exactly* causes this behaviour but you shouldn't be using `<img>` here. It is invalid to have an `<img>` without `src`.

You should use `<div>` instead. See this version: http://jsfiddle.net/r7g8r/3/. It doesn't have this border and works both in Chrome and Firefox (while your version doesn't work in FF).

Comment: well spotted, I totaly overlooked this... You could also just apply the class to the `li`, so you would not require an empty `div` http://jsfiddle.net/r7g8r/4/. Or in real life, add it to an `a`, as this will probably become social links

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.social ul li img
{
border-width:0px;
}
```